# Use PieChart with LiveCharts and WPF .NET Core

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I use chart plugin for WPF:
https://lvcharts.net

In xaml I have:

```
<Window x:Class="GoogleDriveManager.WPF.ChartWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GoogleDriveManager.WPF" xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Chart statistics" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <wpf:PieChart LegendLocation="Bottom" Series="{Binding Items}"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

and code behind:

```
public ChartWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  DataContext = this;

  Items = new SeriesCollection();

  ContentRendered += (s, ev) =>
  {
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> data = GetData(...);
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
      ISeriesView series = new PieSeries(new { title = item.Key });
      IChartValues values = new ChartValues<string>(item.Value);
      series.Values = values;
      Items.Add(series);
    }
  };
}

public SeriesCollection Items { get; }
```

But seems that the window is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should transfer `string` values to `double`
2. Use `PieSeries` properties `Title` to assign title

I create a simple case and this code works:

```cs
ContentRendered += (s, ev) =>
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(){
        {"AAA", new List<string>(){"1","2"}},
        {"BBB", new List<string>(){"3","4"}}
    };
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        var curValues = item.Value.Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();
        ISeriesView series = new PieSeries{
            Title = item.Key,
            Values = new ChartValues<double>(curValues),
            DataLabels = true
        };
        Items.Add(series);
    }
};
```